# testing show/hide with minitest capybara rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, minitest

I'm trying to test the visibility of a div after clicking a button.

```
   assert page.find("#visu")[:class].include?("hidden") # this passes
   assert page.has_xpath?("//*[@id='visu'][contains(@style, 'display: none')]")
   click_button("Show/hide")
   assert page.has_xpath?("//*[@id='visu'][contains(@style, 'display: block')]")
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Any tips?

I am using 'minitest-rails-capybara'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Capybara only finds visible elements, so if you're using one of the drivers that fully processes CSS (pretty much anything except rack_test) then just doing

```
assert_selector(:css, '#visu')
```

would be enough to check for a visible element. If you want to check that an element is specifically non-visible you would need to do

```
assert_selector(:css, '#visu', visible: :hidden)
```

Therefore to test that an element was hidden and then became visible you could do

```
assert_selector(:css, '#visu', visible: :hidden)
click_button("Show/hide")
assert_selector(:css, '#visu')
```

Note that it may not actually make sense to check an element exists but is not-visible it may make more sense to just check that the element isn't there (could be hidden, may not exist) since that way if the button behavior changes to loading the element ( or rendering a template ) the test wouldn't break (and the change in behavior wouldn't have changed the users experience).  To do that you could just do

```
refute_selector(:css, '#visu') # or assert_no_selector depending on preference
click_button('Show/hide')
assert_selector(:css, '#visu')
```

If on the other hand you are using the rack_test driver, it only processes a subsection of CSS/attributes to determine visibility.  In that case an element is considered non-visible if the elements inline style attribute contains `display: none`/`display:none` or if the element has a `hidden` attribute (not a class name of 'hidden'). So if the element was being hidden by a class name 'hide_me' that applied `display:none` in an external css file rack_test would not consider that element hidden.  Instead you could do something like

```
assert_selector(:css, '#visu.hide_me')
```

and the full test would be something like

```
assert_selector(:css, '#visu.hide_me')
click_button("Show/hide")
assert_selector(:css, '#visu:not(.hide_me)')
```

Note: the :css selector type parameter can be omitted if you have not changed Capybara.default_selector.  Additionally error messages are going to be much more descriptive using the `assert_selector` assertion rather than doing `assert page.has_xxx?`

Comment: assert_selector(:css, '#visu')  finds it even if it's hidden, so how can I check if i'm using rack_test?

Comment: @Ayrad read the part of the answer starting with 'If on the other hand ' it's already answered, just replace 'hide_me' with whatever classname hides elements in your app - from you example it's probably 'hidden'

Comment: yes I did read and apply the second part    assert_selector(:css, '#visu.hidden') works perfectly but   assert_selector(:css, '#visu:not(.hidden)') doesn't because jquery does not remove the .hidden from the element I suppose

Comment: @Ayrad If you're using rack_test then JQuery isn't doing anything - The rack_test driver doesn't support JS - you need to use a JS capable driver to test anything that depends on JS behavior